# Get a Power BI desktop version December 2020 2.88.321.0

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Have you still keep the Power BI desktop version December 2020 2.88.321.0 setup or older? Due to my laptop has limited resources that can not be upgraded to Windows 10, this is a reason why I need a Power BI version before Jan 2021 because from Jan 2021, Power BI Desktop is no longer be supported on Windows 7.

I tried to find it in this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/desktop-latest-update-archive?tabs=powerbi-desktop

But for versions before 2021 no have download links.

Comment: Did MSFT decide that everyone was thrilled with the OnObject formatting or whatever junk? I'd like to go back like a year to before that OnObject junk was added. (Or can I just shut it off?

Answer (score 5):

You can download Windows 7 compatible version of Power BI from the following links of original website:

[Power BI Desktop (RS) 64bit](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/0/9/709CBE7F-2005-4A83-B405-CA37A9AB8DC8/PBIDesktopRS_x64.msi)

[Power BI Desktop (RS) 32bit](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/0/9/709CBE7F-2005-4A83-B405-CA37A9AB8DC8/PBIDesktopRS.msi)

I tested 64bit version on Windows 7 and it works correctly.

Version: 2.86.3481.0 (October, 2020)

Comment: The link for 32bits install a 2022 version.

Comment: Unfortunately, micro$oft has no respect for it users, and regularly deletes previously available content according to its actual business interest. This happened to the above links, too.

Answer (score 2):

Power BI 2020 versions (Windows 7 compatible) can be found here: https://zenatti.net/2021/09/12/power-bi-2020-versions/

The last version listed worked for me.

Comment: Tried the last (2.88) x64 version: it's digitally signed by ms, and it works perfectly (after some nudging to update and a reboot not asked for). Thanks.

Comment: Its downloading html file.. Can yu help